# Download a file only if it exists with ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a scraper to download all the issues of The Exile available at http://exile.ru/archive/list.php?IBLOCK_ID=35&PARAMS=ISSUE.

So far, my code is like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'

DATA_DIR = "exile"
Dir.mkdir(DATA_DIR) unless File.exists?(DATA_DIR)
BASE_exile_URL = "http://exile.ru/docs/pdf/issues/exile"
for number in 120..290
  numero = BASE_exile_URL + number.to_s + ".pdf"
  puts "Downloading issue #{number}"
  open(numero) { |f|
    File.open("#{DATA_DIR}/#{number}.pdf",'w') do |file| 
      file.puts f.read 
    end
  }
end

puts "done"
```

The thing is, a lot of the issue links are down, and the code creates a PDF for every issue and, if it's empty, it will leave an empty PDF. How can I change the code so that it can only create and copy a file if the link exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'open-uri'

DATA_DIR = "exile"
Dir.mkdir(DATA_DIR) unless File.exists?(DATA_DIR)
url_template = "http://exile.ru/docs/pdf/issues/exile%d.pdf"
filename_template = "#{DATA_DIR}/%d.pdf"
(120..290).each do |number|
  pdf_url = url_template % number
  print "Downloading issue #{number}"
  # Opening the URL downloads the remote file.
  open(pdf_url) do |pdf_in|
    if pdf_in.read(4) == '%PDF'
      pdf_in.rewind
      File.open(filename_template % number,'w') do |pdf_out|
        pdf_out.write(pdf_in.read)
      end
      print " OK\n"
    else
      print " #{pdf_url} is not a PDF\n"
    end
  end
end

puts "done"
```

`open(url)` downloads the file and provides a handle to a local temp file.  A PDF starts with '%PDF'.  After reading the first 4 characters, if the file is a PDF, the file pointer has to be put back to the beginning to capture the whole file when writing a local copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'

DATA_DIR = "exile"
Dir.mkdir(DATA_DIR) unless File.exists?(DATA_DIR)
BASE_exile_URL = "http://exile.ru/docs/pdf/issues/exile"
  for number in 120..290
    numero = BASE_exile_URL + number.to_s + ".pdf"
    open(numero) { |f|
      content = f.read
      if  content.include? "Link is missing"
        puts "Issue #{number} doesnt exists"
      else
        puts "Issue #{number} exists"
        File.open("./#{number}.pdf",'w') do |file| 
          file.write(content)
        end
      end
      } 
  end
puts "done"
```

The main thing I added is a check to see if the string "Link is missing". I wanted to do it using HTTP status codes but they always give a 200 back, which is not the best practice.

The thing to note is that with my code you always download the whole site to look for that string, but I don't have any other idea to fix it at the moment.

Comment: this one can detect if the file exists or not, but just creates an empty file with the same number of the files that exist, it doesn't write for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to check if exist the file:

```
require 'net/http'

def exist_the_pdf?(url_pdf)
  url = URI.parse(url_pdf)
  Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
    puts http.request_head(url.path)['content-type'] == 'application/pdf'
  end
end
```